# Properties not available in Scene Builder for JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

When trying to use scene builder for a JavaFX project, I am not getting the options in the properties window of containers and controllers that I'm used to getting including resizing, text options, etc...

[image: imgur scene build issue]

On the right hand side you can see there are no available properties to change.

Comment: I seems you are using Scene Builder from insode Intellij. Have you tried the standalone version? MAybe you should file a bug with JetBrains.